# Razor cshtml : Open a modal with data-toggle/data-target inside a post form

Tags: c#, forms, razor, modal-dialog

I'm stuck on a problem right now:

In my cshtml file,
I have a table which display multiple datas, and on each rows we have an "Edit" button.
[The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWvq1.png)

This button (submit) have to open a modal to Edit the data selected.
[the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x22E7.png)

It is doing stuff in the Cshtml.cs
[function used in cshtml.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXOWE.png)

and this is the modal it has to open in the cshtml :
[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tEcy.png)

What is happening?

The call to the function is well executed, and my modal is opening well with the datas in it.
BUT , it is closing right after it appears (between 0.1 and 1 second)

In fact, my submit button is inside a Post form, which permit me to call the csharp function.
But I think the post thing is closing my modal because of a page reset.

[button inside the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P7k8.png)

I dont know how to solve it, and I'm searching here for help.
Thank you very much for reading this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean you want to submit a form and open a model when clicking a button?If so,i think you should use js,or you may reloading the view.(Please share your code without images.)